# Can I get counts for different field values in a MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents that represent orders for laptops. A TypeScript interface for an order is:

```js
interface DeviceOrder {
    _id: uuid,
    manufacturer: "Lenovo" | "Apple" | "HP",
    devices: number,
    sentTo: "Finland" | "Sweden" | "Denmark"
}
```

So a couple of documents could look like, for example:

```json
{
    "_id": "0bdc15a1-168c-4086-aece-473228dcc741",
    "manufacturer": "Apple",
    "devices": 30,
    "sentTo": "Denmark"
}
{
    "_id": "ff8abefb-a39a-4830-9165-356a501ebea9",
    "manufacturer": "Lenovo",
    "devices": 12,
    "sentTo": "Finland"
}
```

I'm trying to build an aggregation pipeline that would give me *for each manufacturer* the total number of orders, the total number of devices ordered, and then a count of devices sent to the different countries:

```js
{
    manufacturer: "Apple",
    orders: 45,
    devices: 332,
    countries: {
        Finland: 300,
        Sweden: 16,
        Denmark: 16
    }
}
```

(Of course the `devices` field isn't essential here, as it's simply a sum of the devices sent to the three different countries)

Is writing a pipeline to get this data the right way to go? And if so, how should I structure it?

Comment: yes, you will need 2 $group stages, first group by manufacturer and country, then group by manufacturer alone.

Comment: You have not provided valid JSON.  It would help you get a prescriptive answer if you provide a valid JSON input document.

Comment: you cannot derive the information you requested.  Your original document does not provide enough detail. You cannot tell if a device is manufactured in "Lenovo", or "Apple", or "HP" in this record.  Nor can you tell if it was sent to "Finland", "Sweden", or "Denmark".   You lack fidelity in your starting model.

Comment: Hey @barrypicker, I believe `manufacturer: "Lenovo" | "Apple" | "HP",`  translates to `manufacturer: {type:{enum:["Lenovo" | "Apple" | "HP"]}}` schemaJson, or "fromArray" type in datagen format. Please check the playground in my answer below.

Comment: @barrypicker Alex Blex is correct, I wrote the order specification in [TypeScript-like syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where vertical bars are used to mark a union of types (in this case, string literals); I'll edit the question to clarify this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 2 $group stages, first group by manufacturer and country, then group by manufacturer alone.

The 3'rd stage is to format "countries" array to an object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "m": "$manufacturer",
        "c": "$sentTo"
      },
      "orders": {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "total": {
        $sum: "$devices"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id.m",
      "orders": {
        $sum: "$orders"
      },
      "devices": {
        $sum: "$total"
      },
      "countries": {
        $push: {
          "k": "$_id.c",
          "v": "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "manufacturer": "$_id",
      "orders": 1,
      "devices": 1,
      "countries": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$countries"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cmsqFMWIhQd